# How to call XML api

Tags: c#, c++, xml, xsd, xml-rpc

I have a set of XML API's ( XSD ) files. I want to call them from C++ and C# programs. These are two different applications.

I want to get data by calling the api. I would also like to know something about XML RPC

Can someone please let me know how do I call the XML api from C++ and C#.

Thanks
Sujay

Answer (score 1):

With C#, use the classes in the [`System.XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml(VS.71).aspx) namespace.

Wikipedia will tell you about [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC).

I don't know what the C++ XML api is.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have any XML processing libraries included by default. If you want the capability, you will need a library. One such library is http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/  / http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/. It should run on most platforms without too much hassle.